# When to use self. prefix when setting variables?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, self

I am working on ARC based project . My outlets are declared  using
unsafe_unretained property . Whenever I am using these outlets I use self.outletname
everywhere in my code.But I have heard people saying , use of self will increase the retain
count and we should use it only for strong properties. I am really confused. Shouldn't we use self for weak properties ?

Comment: Where do people say "use of self will increase the retain

count" ?

Comment: `self.propertyName = newValue` will only increase retain count of `newValue` if it's a retained property. With ARC you do not have to worry about it anyway.

Comment: I was referring to my colleagues. I am sorry if it is wrong . I am a newbie

Comment: @Filip Radelic: U made me clear . Thanks :)

Comment: @vikingosegundo this question is in no way a duplicate of that.

Comment: @Filip Radelic:yes exactly . Thanks for pointing it out . and your answer cleared my doubt . I can accept it if you can post it as an answer

Comment: @FilipRadelic. sure it is. the problem with this Question's description is, that OP also mixed it with his incorrect knowledge of memory management. and BTW: ARC is not a full-featured garbage collection. Your statement "Don't need to worry" is a bad advice.

Comment: @FilipRadelic, also it has nothing to do with Xcode. I will remove the tag the third time now. please stay away from adding it again.

Comment: I dont understand whats wrong with the question. It s not the duplicate of the one listed above in any way . I dont know who down voted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.propertyName = newValue` will only increase retain count of `newValue` if it's a retained property.

Comment: This is very incomplete. Dot notation (`self.whatever`) is the syntax for properties. Properties are just a pair of getter and setter methods. That's it. You're calling a method. It does not have to have anything to do with an instance variable, or retaining. You can (or, in recent versions, the compiler can automatically) *synthesize* the getters and setters based upon an instance variable of your choosing. What the synthesized getter/setter does depends on how the property is declared. If it is declared `retain`, then the setter releases the previous value and retains the new one.

Comment: TLDR: self.propertyName = newValue will only increase retain count of newValue if it's a retained property.